# Grails Spring Security Plugin: How do I use the registration code to invite users to register?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using spring-security-core and spring-security-ui with Grails 1.3.7.

I can't find anything in the docs that explains how to use the Registration Code functionality. I want to have users signup, and then email them a registration code with a link to create their accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the plugin docs at http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/ - in particular section "5 User Registration"

Comment: Burt, there's no mention of the Registration Code feature in the docs that I can find. How is a code generated and associated with a user? You're the man, by the way.

Comment: Ah, I see from the source how the registration code is used. I could do something similar to invite users...

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a slight variation of this in our Grails app, but for you I think the perfect fit should be the [Email Confirmation plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/email-confirmation).